# How can i send app request to both FB friends and application users?

Tags: facebook

**I've a situation in my application where I need to send apprequests (or any way of sending any request to my users) for both my facebook friends as well as the same application users.**

The problem with this is ,

when we are sending apprequests using application itself(using app_access_token) we can't send app requests to my facebook friends who are not yet part of my application (`"oAuthException : User must accept TOS"` will be thrown).

So when i use the '`Request dialog`' (FB.UI app request method) its possible to list/send requests to only FB friends .

So i need a solution for having a method where i can list all my user's FB friends and application users and send apprequest at once to all..

Anybody has tried something like this before?

And also i tried `FB.UI (send method)` and searched for graph API and also considered option of posting wall message and everything doesn't work both types..

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

May I draw your attention to the following Facebook Documentation for AppRequests:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You need to have a look at the section headered "Frictionless requests".

From what I understand from this sentence:

`Upon first sending a request to a friend from within an app, a user may authorize the app to send subsequent requests to the same friend without prompting for his permission.`

It sounds like there is no way to "bulk" send to all of a user's friends, it is on a friend-by-friend basis.  It sounds sensible to me, **I wouldn't want my all of my Facebook friends to be flooded with invitations either**.

You could however opt for prompting the user with the Friend Request interface which is much friendlier to your users... this is available using the [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

[image: Friend request interface]

Comment: This is want i'm using for sending requests to my FB friends, this is what i meant as 'Request Dialog' but my main concern is that i need to club both My fb friends and my friends from the application and need to display them in one window and on selection of users from that list i need to send requests to them.. I never wanted to send request to all friends at once...  I think i've stated more clear now..

Comment: So you want to manipulate the FB.UI interface to show something other than what it would show by default?

Comment: Not in that way. I was thinking to create my custom dialog with all my fb friends and also my friends inside application and give users option to select them, once selected based on the user type(FB friend or application friend) can i send same kind of requests using different methods...?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that the sending of requests is restricted to the provided dialogs.

Comment: No, we can send app requests from the application itself, but its restricted to the users who are already using the application. For this we can use graph api and this api request needs applicatiion_access_token instead of user_access_token.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/ - see "PHP example of an app-generated request"